# Why am I getting a SEGV error at these two lines? What could be wrong in these lines?

Tags: segmentation-fault

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JVF0.jpg)

One of errors I have shown here, the other line does similar work as it also tries to update another variable of person. So what is wrong here?

Comment: Please do not post text as image.

Comment: What lines do you mean?